# Move form only vertically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to create a WinForms form which will be moved by TitleBar only vertically?

Comment: Move automatcially?? What do you mean  by "moved by"?

Comment: I mean when user moves the form, it shouldn't be moved horizontally - only vertically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to intercept the WM_MOVING notification message that Windows sends.  Here's the code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private struct RECT {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            if (m.Msg == 0x216) {  // Trap WM_MOVING
                var rc = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(RECT));
                int w = rc.right - rc.left;
                rc.left = this.Left;
                rc.right = rc.left + w;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, false);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do it (but it's not pretty) :

```
    private void MainForm_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Left = 100;
    }
```

Comment: This is the best solution and twitching is unavoidable. That said, this behaviour is confusing for the end user, who legitimately thinks he can drag windows around. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can shortcut the move operation by resetting the Location of your form to the initial X value and the Y value of the move.  This solution is simple, but will flicker a bit.

```
protected Point StartPosition { get; set; }

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    StartPosition  = this.Location;
}

protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
{
    if (StartPosition == new Point())
        return;

    var currentLocation = Location;

    Location = new Point(StartPosition.X, currentLocation.Y);

    base.OnMove(e);
}
```