# Preventing a window from leaving MDI without twitching?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, window, mdi

On my Form1's Move event, I check its position and if its out of the view of the user I move it back. Is there an event that fires when he is done moving it? Because the move event fires kind of while its being moved, I need it to be after its moved. Here is my code so far:

```
    private void PublicTicker_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Left < 0)
        { this.Left = 0; }

        else if (this.Left > this.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Width - this.Width)
        { this.Left = this.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Width - this.Width; }

        if (this.Top < 3)
        { this.Top = 3; }

        else if (this.Top > this.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Height)
        { this.Top = this.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Height - this.Height; }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move form only vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302440/move-form-only-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try performing your move correction routines in **ResizeEnd** event. Surprisingly it is fired not only when form is resized but also when form is moved by user.

Read more [Form.ResizeEnd Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx).