# Move form only horizontal

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to move windows form only horizontal? I made position top left `Dim scr = Screen.FromPoint(Me.Location)
        Me.Location = New Point(0, scr.WorkingArea.Top)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)` but I would to remake it to be able to move the form only hozitontal.

Answer (score -1):

To move the form horizontally:

```
Me.Left += 50
```

Or, with the same way that you show:

```
Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 50, Me.Location.Y)
```

To prevent to form to be moved vertically/horizontally by the user (in case is that what you're asking, not  clear to me) you can take a look at this: [Move form only vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302440/move-form-only-vertically)